# getting preferences for ReadReceiptRequested and OriginatorDeliveryReportRequested from MailItem without triggering Outlook Security Patch

Tags: outlook-redemption

I would like to use Redemption library (currently on version 5.27.0.6916) to get preferences for properties **ReadReceiptRequested** and **OriginatorDeliveryReportRequested** by creating a new MailItem in Inbox Folder and reading them.
Accessing them via Outlook Object Model (OOM) interop triggers the Outlook Security Patch, resulting in a confirmation dialog/security prompt (strangely enough, this only seems to happen in a terminalserver session).

I tried to use SafeMailItem, but those properties are not implemented.

I have a fallback to read from registry, but is there a way to do this with Redemption?
And is there an explanation for why this would only happen in a terminalserver session?

`

```
var mailItem = Folders.NewItem<MailItem>(Stores.Get(accountId), DefaultFolders.Inbox); 

try
{
    return new CMailPreferences
    {
        DeliveryReceiptRequested = mailItem.OriginatorDeliveryReportRequested,
        ReadReceiptRequested = mailItem.ReadReceiptRequested,
    };
}
finally
{
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(mailItem);
}
```

`

Comment: Is that a security prompt or a prompt to send the read notifications?

Comment: There is a security prompt; Í amended the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to create an instance of the `RDOSession` object (once, not in a loop) and call `RDOSession.GetRDOObjectFromOutlookObject(mailItem)` to open the item as `RDOMail` object.